# React JS: How to send data from one Component to another Component onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I am designing a bike rental app. The main Area page displays the bikes available with the names, models and images of the bike in Cards. Now when we click on book we are redirected to the Checkout page. I need to send the name and model information of the bike selected to the Checkout page. How to do that?

BikesCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button
} from 'reactstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class BikesCard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log(this.props.bikes)
    this.props.propdata.history.push(`/Checkout`)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card className="Card">
          <CardImg top width="100%" src={this.props.bikes.image} alt="Card image cap" />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{this.props.bikes.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardSubtitle>{this.props.bikes.model}</CardSubtitle>
            <CardText>{this.props.bikes.description}</CardText>
            <Button onClick={this.handleClick}>Book</Button>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default BikesCard;
```

Checkout.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import NavBar from './NavBar.jsx';

class Checkout extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.bikes);
    this.state = {
      
    };

    this.confirmClick = this.confirmClick.bind(this);
    this.goBackClick = this.goBackClick.bind(this);
  }

  confirmClick() {
    this.props.history.push("/myBookings");
  }

  goBackClick() {
    this.props.history.push("/home");
  }

  render() {
    
    let btnstyle = "10px 0%";
    return (
      <div>

        <NavBar/>
          <Button onClick={this.confirmClick}>Confirm Booking</Button>
          <Button onClick={this.goBackClick}>Go Back</Button>

        // should display Card with the details of the bike which is selected. It should have two buttons i.e, confirm booking button and go back buttton
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Checkout;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data with history.push like this:

```
this.props.propData.history.push({ 
 pathname: '/checkout',
 state: data_you_need_to_pass
});
```

And read it from /checkout like this:

```
const data = this.props.location.state;
```

You can read more [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history)